# Tensorflow Object detection in Google Colab error: module 'nets' has no attribute 'autograd'

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Hello everyone I am trying to do object detection on custom data using TensorFlow in google colab, so I used the TensorFlow model zoo when I try to do the training using this code:

```
import os
!pip install tf_slim
%cd '/content/models/research/object_detection'
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += '/content/models/research/object_detection'
!python /content/models/research/object_detection/legacy/train.py --train_dir=training/ -- 
 pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config --logtostderr
```

i got this error :

```
    Requirement already satisfied: tf_slim in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.2.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tf_slim) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from absl-py>=0.2.2->tf_slim) (1.15.0)
/content/models/research/object_detection
WARNING:tensorflow:
The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/io (for I/O related ops)
If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/try/models/research/object_detection/legacy/train.py", line 53, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 35, in <module>
    from object_detection.models import faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor as frcnn_inc_res
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/models/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor.py", line 28, in <module>
    from nets import inception_resnet_v2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nets/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from nets.autograd import Hook, Parameter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nets/autograd/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .functional import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nets/autograd/functional.py", line 15, in <module>
    import nets.autograd.function as fc
AttributeError: module 'nets' has no attribute 'autograd'
```

i was thinking that maybe i didn't install everything in the models directory, but i used the **setup.py** and i run it.

I will be happy to get the answer from you, thank you

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem on local installation.
This is because you probably did

```
pip install nets
```

This installs a wrong module named `nets`. What you should do is

```
pip uninstall nets
```

Then go to folder `research/slim` and remove the whole folder build.
Then perform in this folder

```
python setup install
```

Then you shouldn't have this problem anymore since `nets` from `slim` folder was used.

On Windows I also needed `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable to be set to the `research` folder.